# MATLAB randsample in function form

Tags: matlab, function, random

The goal is generating six lotto numbers, but obviously they have to be unique. This has to be written in function form though, following is the equivalent using the library:

```
    (randsample(42,6))'
```

My idea was to create the vector with all possibilities, pick one out at a time through index and making it impossible to pick this one again by grabbing it out before the next one is picked.

```
    function numbers = lottonumbers()

    pool = 1:42;
    numbers = zeros(1,6); 

    for i=1:6
        for j=42-i

            randIndex = round(1+j*rand);
            randNumber = pool(randIndex);
            numbers(i) = randNumber;

            if randIndex==1
                pool = pool(2:end);
            else if randIndex==length(pool)
                pool = pool(1:(end-1));
            else  
                pool = [pool(1:randIndex-1), pool(randIndex+1:end)];
                 end
            end
        end   
     end
```

Since I'm pretty noob at MATLAB (just noob at programming really) and since I solved it myself while asking the question, I'm just going to leave it here and ask you guys for suggestions (better style, other algorithm...)

Answer (score 1):

Lotto is based on permutations where the order does not play a role.

```
% p = randperm(n,k) returns a row vector containing k unique integers selected randomly from 1 to n inclusive.
randperm( 42, 6 )
```

should do the trick.

From the code: "This is sometimes referred to as a K-permutation of 1:N or as sampling without replacement."

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling): generate the numbers independently, and if they are not all different start again. This is efficient as long as the chance of numbers not being all different is small.

```
N = 6;
M = 42;
done = false;
while ~done
    result = randi(M,1,N); %// generate N numbers from [1,...,M]
    done = all(diff(sort(result))); %// if all are different, we're done
end
```